# lineplot smoothing in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, grouping, smoothing

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302381/how-to-smooth-lines-that-go-exactly-though-the-datapoints-ggplot

I am trying to make this picture in r

[image: descr]

However, this is how far i have come so far.

[image: descr]

these are my data
[image: descr]

and codes

```
g0 <- ggplot(data = plot.m, aes(x = Var1,  y = value, group=Var2)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Var2))+geom_line()
```

g0

- Can somebody help in getting smooth lines here that go through all
  data points?
- help to put x-axis labels little bit (about 2 cm) below?

Comment: Here is an earlier answer that seems very similar to your needs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205795/plotting-smooth-line-through-all-data-points

Comment: thanks. it worked!!